# Multiple consoles for one user

Tags: ibm-cloud

I recently signed up for bluemix and suddenly I see two consoles url when I try to log in. Which is confusing me.
Can some one explain the difference between these.

```
https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/
and
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/
```

I can see all my test application that I created are part of "https://console.ng.bluemix.net/"

Though bluemix is allowing me to create applications in "eu-gb" doamin as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluemix has different [hosting regions](https://www.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/#overview/overview.html#ov_intro__reg) and you can create apps and services in them. Right now there are two hosting regions (data centers) for the public Bluemix. Hence the two consoles you are seeing.

Try switching to the "eu-gb" region, create a service there, and notice that the second console shows a service, too. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer.
That's what I assumed, but is there any way to switch "regions" when I am logged in. I couldn't find any region switch and suddenly all my application went off untill accidently I noticed the URL

Comment: Never mind I located that in the user account section. Thanks !

Comment: On the upper right corner should be your profile/account button. Click on it and then on the lower part of the list are the available regions and a link to the concept of regions: https://www.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/#overview/overview.html#ov_intro__reg